CORS issue when calling laravel api from React application
I have a laravel(8.12) backend application running on Xampp with PHP(8) on url http://localhost/testbe
My frontend is running on http://localhost:3000
My frontend is making get api via axios.
Axios configuration
const api = axios.create({
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
   },
  withCredentials: true,
});

The api is giving below error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/testbe/api/v1/admin/roles' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

./config/cors.php
<?php

return [

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:3000'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => false,

];

./app/http/kernel.php
<?php

protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];


./

When i am logging the request at the end of handle method in Fruitcake/cors package, output is below:
[2024-06-06 21:39:48] local.ALERT: HTTP/1.0 204 No Content
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-xsrf-token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Max-Age:       0
Cache-Control:                no-cache, private
Date:                         Thu, 06 Jun 2024 16:09:48 GMT
Vary:                         Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers

Chrome Developer tools output:
HTTP/1.0 204 No Content
Date: Thu, 06 Jun 2024 16:20:50 GMT

Server: Apache/2.4.58 (Win64) OpenSSL/3.1.3 PHP/8.2.12
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.2.12
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Max-Age: 0
Connection: close
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-headers: *
access-control-expose-headers: *


The error of

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/testbe/api/v1/admin/roles' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

suggests that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header of the target site has a wildcard value of * which is not compatible with the include as the request's credential mode. In order to make this work, you either need to change your request to have false for withCredentials or, alternatively you could explicitly specify the origin from the site you have targeted, provided that you have control over it.

I have added the config.php file above in the question. After debug it is logging the correct output with specified origin, but in chrome developer tools, i am receiving *
